# Rails e-mail options, Sidekiq, Sendgrid, Mandrill and delay times

Tags: email, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer, sendgrid, mandrill

Trying to understand more about Rails and e-mail before beginning to set it all up. E-mail news notifications are already a big part of what we do and automating and improving that bit (currently MailChimp) is part of the reason for rewriting it all in Rails. From an editorial and business perspective, we want news e-mails going out to subscribers as soon as the story is published, especially for breaking stories, so as the service grows, we're looking at thousands of e-mails a day.

Are things like Sendgrid and Mandrill a substitute for trying to roll your own with Rails and Sidekiq/Resque/Delayed Job, or is it necessary to do something like Sidekiq + Sendgrid?

Assuming we use deliver_now + Sendgrid, does anyone know how long it takes before e-mails start hitting inboxes? Are we talking a couple of minutes or half an hour or an hour?

Answer (score 2):

With any of the services you mention, you'll still want to use a worker queue on the client side to make sure that if you have any problems you can easily check status and retry.

I can't speak for the other services but with SendGrid you'll be looking at delivery times in the range of seconds rather than minutes.

Comment: Thank you bwest, sorry, your answer had slipped through the net somehow. Seconds sounds good. So in theory it would be possible to do both for max. efficiency: an API call instead of smtp and a background job?